# Autocomplete de preenchimento dinâmico

Tags: bootstrap-3, chosen-jquery-plugin

Estou tentando usar o [Bootstrap + Chosen](http://alxlit.name/bootstrap-chosen/), no meu `select option` para fazer um combobox com **autocomplete**.

Só que estou fazendo o preenchimento do select dinamicamente com jquery.

Mas ao implementar o Bootstrap + Chosen o preenchimento dinâmico não funciona, enquanto que o chosen funciona e se eu tirar o chosen o preenchimento dinâmico funciona.

Meu preenchimento está assim:

```
function carregarComboSetor( idSetor ){
      $.ajax({
          url      : 'funcao/setor.php',
          type     : 'post',
          dataType : 'json',
          data : {
            acao : 'S',
            cdsetor : idSetor
          },
          success : function (data) {
              var op = "<option value='0'>Selecione um setor</option>";
              $('#setor').append(op);
              $.each( data.setor, function (key, value) {
                  var option = "";
                  if( idSetor === value.codsetor ){
                      option = "<option value='"+ value.codsetor +"' selected>"
                                 + value.nmsetor
                               +"</option>";

                  }else{
                      option = "<option value='"+ value.codsetor +"'>"
                               + value.nmsetor
                               +"</option> ";
                  }
                 $('#setor').append(option);
              } );
              $('#setor').val( idSetor );
          }

      });

}
```

> **EDIÇÂO** 1

No console só mostra esses textos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja se está retornando algum `erro` no console.log

Comment: Não retornar erros, na verdade só que aqueles avisos conforme edição

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver!

Adicionei dentro da minha função de carregar Combo a seguinte linha:

```
$('#setor').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Ficando assim:

```
function carregarComboSetor( idSetor ){
    /* resto do codigo **/
          success : function (data) {

               /* resto do codigo **/

              $.each( data.setor, function (key, value) {
                 /* resto do codigo **/

              } );
             /* resto do codigo **/
              $('#setor').trigger("chosen:updated");
          }

      });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que deverias fazer o *parse* do **json** recebido pela função `success`:

```
function carregarComboSetor( idSetor ){
      $.ajax({
          url      : 'funcao/setor.php',
          type     : 'post',
          dataType : 'json',
          data : {
            acao : 'S',
            cdsetor : idSetor
          },
          success : function (data) {

              var data = JSON.parse(data); // esta linha

              var op = "<option value='0'>Selecione um setor</option>";
              $('#setor').append(op);
              $.each( data.setor, function (key, value) {
                  var option = "";
                  if( idSetor === value.codsetor ){
                      option = "<option value='"+ value.codsetor +"' selected>"
                                 + value.nmsetor
                               +"</option>";

                  }else{
                      option = "<option value='"+ value.codsetor +"'>"
                               + value.nmsetor
                               +"</option> ";
                  }
                 $('#setor').append(option);
              } );
              $('#setor').val( idSetor );
          }

      });

}
```

Comment: Mas o combobox só não funciona se eu colocar no final da página `$('#setor').chosen();`. Fora isso a minha função funciona normalmente.